# How to retrieve data from an SQLite database and assign it to a variable

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite, select

I need to retrieve a password from a database and assign it to a string so I can cross check it with the contents of a textbox.

```
sSql = "SELECT login_password FROM Login WHERE login_username = '" & txtUsername.Text & "';"
```

This is the command I need but I'm not sure how to use it or how to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: There is no need to create sock puppet accounts to ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49467502/1070452)

Comment: Are you familiar with ADO.net? Can you connect to the database. Do you know how to create a command? Search on these subjects and get some code going, then post a question where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
 public boolean checkPassword(String user, String pass){
       try{
           Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:HM.db");
           Statement stm = con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN");
           while(rs.next()){
               String u = rs.getString("USERNAME");
               String p = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
               System.out.println("Checking...");
               System.out.println("User = " +u +"password= " +p);
               System.out.println("User = " +user +"password= " +pass);
               if(p.equals(pass) && u.equals(user)){
                   System.out.println("True");
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
       System.out.println("false");
       return false;
    }
```

Then, call this Method on LogIn Butoon like:

```
checkpassword(txtUsrname, login_password);
```

Tell me if this worked.

Comment: forgot to mention i'm using Visual Basic

Comment: Oh.
oops!
Can't help then. :\

Comment: You'd _pull the entire table_ back to the client and check it there?